# Notify the Multiple instances of UI using Wcf service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a application in WPF, which will allow me to add,delete and edit student. That UI can be opened more than once.
When the UI makes change to the data through the service every other connected client should also be updated with latest changes.

Is that possible to have wcf service do it for me? How can we do it?

Comment: "Yes". If this is not a helpful answer, you may want to ask another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each WPF UI window should establish a connection with the host WCF Service.

The Service is required to be a of singleton type.
Also you'll have to enable session.

Each UI window should start have it's own connection with the service. And must also handle callback method.

The service must track these session and callback method ID.

Now when a UI thread makes change to the data (I am assuming using the WCF service in consideration) the service will have to iterate the session collection and send notification.

There are only two binding that support this `netTcp` and `WSDualHttp`.

The Service and Callback service would look as below:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required,
    CallbackContract = typeof(INotifyMeDataUpdate))]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating=true)]
    void Register();

    [OperationContract(IsTerminating= true)]
    void Unregister();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void Message(string theMessage);
}

public interface INotifyMeDataUpdate
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void GetUpdateNotification(string updatedData);
}
```

The implementation would as below:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Service : IService
{
    object _lock = new object();
    Dictionary<string, INotifyMeDataUpdate> _UiThreads =
        new Dictionary<string, INotifyMeDataUpdate>();

    public void Register()
    {
        string id = OperationContext.Current.SessionId;

        if (_UiThreads.ContainsKey(id)) _UiThreads.Remove(id);
        _UiThreads.Add(id, OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<INotifyMeDataUpdate>());
    }

    public void Unregister()
    {
        string id = OperationContext.Current.SessionId;

        if (_UiThreads.ContainsKey(id)) _UiThreads.Remove(id);
    }

    public void Message(string theMessage)
    {
        foreach (var key in _UiThreads.Keys)
        {
            INotifyMeDataUpdate registeredClient = _UiThreads[key];
            registeredClient.GetUpdateNotification(theMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first three statements are false.

Comment: if each UI window is not registering with the service is there a way WCF service can track open UI windows and notify back? Am I any closer to the solution? Could you correct me please?

Comment: You'll want to register this at the application level, not at the window level. The service doesn't have to be singleton.

Comment: if the service is not singleton there would be no tracking of the registered UI Windows. I've created a small demo could you have a look please and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: With the code instance added above I am pretty certain that
- it has to be singleton
- Each window should register with the service
- And must handle a call back as well.

@CodeCaster: Could you please comment sir? Thanks.

Comment: probably I need to revise my sentence but this is what I tried to communicate. Would you be able to do it for me @CodeCaster? thanks.

Comment: I meant there are other ways of achieving this. The service shouldn't have to know about client windows. But you gave an example implementation, so have an upvote. :-)